# Expressive macro for tensors; raised and lowered indices

Tags: macros, equations

Does anyone have a satisfying solution to the problem of typesetting tensors with raised/lowered indices? For example, I can write the following equation:
`\ddot x^\mu = \Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\alpha}{}_{\beta} \dot x^\alpha \dot x^\beta`

[image]

When writing a lot of tensors, this is cumbersome.

What I'm looking for is a way to construct a command which can produce tensors like `\Gamma` above with more expressive syntax. For example, a command `\tens` that operates like this would be ideal:

`\ddot \tens{x}{\mu} = \tens{Gamma}{\mu}[\alpha][\beta] \dot \tens{x}{\alpha} \tens{x}{\beta}`

The key quality of *my desired syntax* is that there is an arbitrary number of arguments of *two distinct types*. Argument encased in `{ }` are raised indices, while arguments encased in `[ ]` are lowered indices. I don't need a command that looks *exactly* like this; I am looking for something that is similarly expressive.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? An implementation of a `\tens` command that works as above? I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Potentially useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98443/218142

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL - thanks. I don't know how to adjust the answer there, and it's a different problem because in this case there is no fixed number of arguments. For my use case, upper and lower indices may occur any number of times, and in any order.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually possible for the `\tens` function to determine when its argument list has ended... maybe I need to declare the total number of upper and lower indices as an argument to `\tens`.

Comment: With the `tensor` package you can type `\tensor{\Gamma}{^\mu_\alpha_\beta}` which seems not far from your idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, the subscripts and superscripts *are* a single argument.

You can use the `tensor` package, without reinventing the wheel: it has a very handy syntax.

I also provide a `\tens` command according to your preferences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}

%\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tens}{mo}
 {
  #1
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 } 
   {
    \__myridium_tens_up_lookup:
   }
   {
    \__myridium_tens_down_lookup: [ #2 ]
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__myridium_tens_down_lookup:
 {
  \peek_charcode_ignore_spaces:NTF [
   {
    \__myridium_tens_down:w
   }
   { \kern2\scriptspace }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__myridium_tens_down:w [ #1 ]
 {
  {\mathstrut}
  \sb{#1}
  \kern-\scriptspace
  \__myridium_tens_up_lookup:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__myridium_tens_up_lookup:
 {
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_group_begin_token
   {
    \__myridium_tens_up:n
   }
   { \kern2\scriptspace }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__myridium_tens_up:n
 {
  {\mathstrut}
  \sp{#1}
  \kern-\scriptspace
  \__myridium_tens_down_lookup:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\subsection*{With \texttt{tensor}}
\[
\tensor{\ddot{x}}{^\mu}=
\tensor{\Gamma}{^\mu_\alpha_\beta}
\tensor{\dot{x}}{^\alpha} \tensor{\dot{x}}{^\beta}
\]

\[
\tensor{\Gamma}{_\mu^\nu^\rho_\alpha^\nu^\rho}
\tensor{\dot{\Gamma}}{_\mu^\nu^\rho_\alpha^\nu^\rho}
\]

\subsection*{With the hand-made macro}
\[
\tens{\ddot{x}}{\mu}=
\tens{\Gamma}{\mu}[\alpha\beta]
\tens{\dot{x}}{\alpha} \tens{\dot{x}}{\beta}
\]

\[
\tens{\Gamma}[\mu]{\nu\rho}[\alpha]{\nu\rho}
\tens{\dot{\Gamma}}[\mu]{\nu\rho}[\alpha]{\nu\rho}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you are making there is equivalent in all but name to having a `g`-type argument, which is something you seem to strongly oppose. I don’t quite understand why  `g`-types are supposed to be awful, but *de facto* `g`-types are fine.

Comment: @Gaussler I answered the OP's question. This doesn't mean I endorse this kind of syntax, as explained in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the `tensor` package. I agree it is syntactically better. Where should I go to learn how to understand the custom `\tens` command you defined?

Comment: @Myridium That's just a proof-of-concept written in the `expl3` language. Do `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3`.

Comment: Regarding the `tensor` package, the maintainer sent me an updated version that addresses the issue raised in this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558820/218142. The update has not yet been pushed to `CTAN` however.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn’t use such a syntax, but [SemanTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/semantex) can be set up to accomplish something resembling this (disclaimer: I am the author). Note that you will need a recent update of SemanTeX (October or later, I think) for this example to work. Note that I also prefer defining keys `dot` and `ddot` instead of directly using the commands `\dot` and `\ddot`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{semantex}

\NewVariableClass\tens[
    output=\tens,
    define keys={
        {dot}{ command=\dot },
        {ddot}{ command=\ddot },
        {pre index}{ right return, symbol put right={{}} },
        {post index}{ right return, symbol put right=\kern-\scriptspace },
    },
    define keys[1]={
        {default}{ pre index, lower={#1}, post index },
        {arg}{ pre index, upper={#1}, post index },
    },
]

\begin{document}

$ \tens{\dot x}{\mu} = \tens{\dot{\Gamma}}{\mu}[\alpha][\beta] 
    \tens{\dot{x}}{\alpha} \tens{\dot{x}}{\beta} $

$ \tens{\ddot x}{\mu} = \tens{\dot{\Gamma}}{\mu}[\alpha][\beta]
    \tens{\dot{x}}{\alpha} \tens{\dot{x}}{\beta} $

$ \tens{x}[ddot]{\mu} = \tens{\Gamma}[dot]{\mu}[\alpha][\beta]
    \tens{x}[dot]{\alpha} \tens{x}[dot]{\beta} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Personally, I would prefer to use a more keyval-based syntax, as below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{semantex}

\NewVariableClass\Tensor[
    output=\Tensor,
    define keys={
        {dot}{ command=\dot },
        {ddot}{ command=\ddot },
        {pre index}{ right return, symbol put right={{}} },
        {post index}{ right return, symbol put right=\kern-\scriptspace },
    },
    define keys[1]={
        {up}{ pre index, upper={#1}, post index },
        {low}{ pre index, lower={#1}, post index },
    },
]

\begin{document}

$ \Tensor{x}[dot,up=\mu] = \Tensor{\Gamma}[dot,up=\mu,low=\alpha,low=\beta]
    \Tensor{x}[dot,up=\alpha] \Tensor{x}[dot,up=\beta] $

$ \Tensor{x}[dot,up=\mu] = \Tensor{\Gamma}[dot,up=\mu,low=\alpha,low=\beta]
    \Tensor{x}[dot,up=\alpha] \Tensor{x}[dot,up=\beta] $

\NewObject\Tensor\tGamma{\Gamma}
\NewObject\Tensor\tx{x}

$ \tx[dot,up=\mu] = \tGamma[dot,up=\mu,low=\alpha,low=\beta]
    \tx[dot,up=\alpha] \tx[dot,up=\beta] $

$ \tx[dot,up=\mu] = \tGamma[dot,up=\mu,low=\alpha,low=\beta]
    \tx[dot,up=\alpha] \tx[dot,up=\beta] $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that works like you describe but with round brackets instead of curly ones. As usual such things can be a bit fragile, so occasionally you need to `\relax` a bit to mark it fully work, as can be seen in the second example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\edef\tens@u{(}
\edef\tens@l{[}
\def\tens@U#1)#2{{}^{#1}\expandafter\tens@i#2\relax}
\def\tens@L#1]#2{{}_{#1}\expandafter\tens@i#2\relax}
\def\tens@i#1#2{\edef\tens@t{#1}%
\ifx\tens@t\tens@u
\expandafter\tens@U#2
\else
\ifx\tens@t\tens@l
\expandafter\tens@L#2
\else
#1#2
\fi
\fi}
\def\tens#1#2{#1\expandafter\tens@i#2}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
works: &
$\tens{\Gamma}[\mu](\nu\rho)[\alpha](\nu\rho) \dot\tens{x}(\alpha)
\dot\tens{x}(\beta)$ \\[2em]

does not work: & 
$\tens{\Gamma}[\mu](\nu\rho)[\alpha](\nu\rho) \dot\tens{x}(\alpha)
\tens{x}(\beta)$ \\[2em]

relax and it works again: &
$\tens{\Gamma}[\mu](\nu\rho)[\alpha](\nu\rho) \dot\tens{x}(\alpha)\relax
\tens{x}(\beta)$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To be clear: such macros are mainly for recreation purposes and not for the real world. These days the LaTeX world has enough other problems...

Answer (score 1):

The definition of your desired macro `\tens` using TeX primitives follows:

```
\def\tens#1{#1\futurelet\next\tensA}
\def\tensA{\def\tensX{}%
   \ifx\next[\def\tensX[##1]{{}_{##1}\futurelet\next\tensA}\fi 
   \ifx\next\bgroup \def\tensX##1{{}^{##1}\futurelet\next\tensA}\fi
   \tensX}

%% test:

$\tens\Gamma [\mu]{\nu\rho}[\alpha]{\nu\rho}$

$\ddot\tens{x}{\mu} = \tens{\Gamma}{\mu}[\alpha][\beta] 
                      \dot\tens{x}{\alpha} \dot\tens{x}{\beta}$
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest and I could probably reverse engineer this to learn something.

Comment: You need not to do complicate reverse engineering: there are only four well documented TeX primitives `\def`, `\futurelet`, `\ifx`, `\fi`.