# Is it possible to use multiple sub- or superscript syntax in math mode?

Tags: macros, subscripts, syntax, arguments, tensor

I often have to write expressions like this in math mode:

```
L_t^pL_x^q
```

[image: Desired output]

For some reason, I am not always satisfied with typing this and I would like to define some new command with the same output. I was thinking whether it could be possible to define a command with the same output for which the code would look like the following:

```
\LL_t_x^p^q
```

I have found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572541/expressive-macro-for-tensors-raised-and-lowered-indices) concerning tensors that looks quite related (see the first answer). The syntax used in the package "tensor" would be quite good, but I don't know how to replicate a command with that syntax.

My questions are the following:

1. Even though the syntax in the package "tensor" is quite nice, in my deepest dreams I would like to be able to use the exact same one in the command that I wrote above: `\LL_x_t^p^q`. So, would there be a way of designing a command that works as above (that is, a command of the form `\LL_t_x^p^q` which has the same output of `L_t^pL_x^q`)?
2. If not, how can I design a command with the same syntax of the package "tensor"? That is (if I understand correctly), a generic command with 3 classes of inputs `\arg`, `\superscriptI,\superscriptII,...`, `\subscriptI,\subscriptII,...` with the following syntax:

```
\commandname{\arg}{^\superscriptI_\subscriptI_\subscriptII^\superscriptII...}
```

(in my case, I would like to write a command of the form `\LL{_x_t^p^q}`, with the same output as `L_t^pL_x^q`).

Comment: Would `\LL_{t,x}^{p,q}` be an alternative?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If you are talking about the syntax, yes, this is close to what I want, even though I would prefer the syntax of the package "tensor". (Just to be clear) if you are talking about the output of your command, it is not what I am looking for: I would like to have some indices after the first L and some indices after the second L

Comment: It would be more natural to not have the subscript and superscript tokens as parameter separators, but preferably defnine `\newcommand\LL[4]{L_{#1}^{#3}L_{#2}^{#4}}` and invoke it as `\LL{t{x}{p{}q}` (or `\LL txpq` if you are lazy)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\LL{\futurelet\tmp\LLx}
\def\LLx{\ifx\tmp_\expandafter\LLxx\fi}
\def\LLxx_#1#2^#3{L_{#1}^{#3}\LL#2}

\begin{document}

$\LL_t_x^p^q$

$\LL$

$\LL_t_x_a^p^q^b$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The use case shows some possible variations in the input syntax, all of which give the desired output.  For example, `\LL_x_t^p^q$`, `$\LL_x^p_t^q$`, and `$\LL^p_x_t^q$` all produce identical output.

EDITED to permit embraced sub or superscripts, for example, of the form `\LL_{x_a}_t^p^q`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand\LL{
  \toks0{}\toks2{}
  \def\subbase{0}
  \def\supbase{0}
  \LLdigest
}
\newcommand\LLdigest[2]{
  \ifx_#1
    \toks\subbase\expandafter{\the\toks\subbase#1{#2}}
    \def\subbase{2}
    \def\next{\LLdigest}
  \else
    \ifx^#1
      \toks\supbase\expandafter{\the\toks\supbase#1{#2}}
      \def\supbase{2}
    \def\next{\LLdigest}
    \else
      L\the\toks0L\the\toks2 
      \def\next{#1#2}
    \fi
  \fi
  \next
}
\begin{document} 
$\LL_x_t^p^q$ 

$\LL_x^p_t^q$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I probably need some time to "digest" your code, but it looks exactly what I wanted

Comment: @LorenzoPompili You are welcome.  I essentially build two token lists (0 and 2).  The first sub and superscript are assigned to `\toks0`, later ones assigned to `\toks2`.  When I run out of digesting sub or superscripts, I end the digestion.

Answer (score 4):

I can propose a slightly different syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\LL}{e{_^}}{%
  \LLaux{#1}{#2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\LLaux}{%
  >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m
  >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m
}{%
  \LLauxa#1#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\LLauxa}{mmmm}{%
  L_{#1\vphantom{#2}}^{#3\vphantom{#4}}
  L_{#2\vphantom{#1}}^{#4\vphantom{#3}}
}

\begin{document}

$\LL_{t,x}^{p,q}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if *all* your instances of `\LL` have the form

```
\LL_t_x^p^q
```

that is, in every call there are two subscripts and two superscripts, the solution is more straightforward:

```
\newcommand{\LL}{} % for safety
\def\LL_#1_#2^#3^#4{%
  L_{#1\vphantom{#2}}^{#3\vphantom{#4}}%
  L_{#2\vphantom{#1}}^{#4\vphantom{#3}}%
}
```